# Encryption Technique to Generate Smaller string in Java

Tags: java, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I want to encrypt and decrypt some string which may be between 300 to 1000 characters long. I am going to save these encrypted values in cookies. So I want to know if any encryption APIs available which generates smaller encrypted strings, may be same or lesser length than actual string.

Thanks.

Comment: why not simply combine an encryption and compression algorithm (i'd recommend compression first)?

Comment: Just to be sure, you're talking about encryption so you want to recover the plaintext from the cipher text, right?

Comment: yes. I want save this encrypted information in cookie and later retrieve it for further usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, compress the string first as @Paul suggested and base64 encode it if you want to keep it as nice string but not as byte array, and after encrypt. May be it will fill your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetric encryption is a general facility so that you can *encrypt* a message in clear (*cleartext*) to its encrypted equivalent (*ciphertext*) and decrypt back using a key, called the **private key**. Whoever has the key will be able to do this operation back and forth (hence the word symmetric).This, as you know, is very different from encoding/decoding where there is no private key involved, knowing the encoding algorithm is enough to decode (e.g. Base 64).

You seem to have an additional requirement that the *ciphertext* should be **shorter** than *cleartext*. Some compression techniques can be utilized, but this is tricky and perhaps uncalled for in your use case. In general, if you use SymmetricEncryption utility like [this](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/7398a49fe182d196282a) (real code, try with Java 8) you will see that the *ciphertext* is **longer** than *ciphertext* (not what you want).

Lastly, this solution may be complicated for your use case. If I understand correctly, you want to identify an HTTP session with some information. If you store that information in the cookie, yes, you will need to secure that information so that your solution is at least as secure as the cookie itself. But in such cases, you use the server side storage for session, rather than the cookie store. See how this is done [using Rails](http://dev.housetrip.com/2014/01/14/session-store-and-security/) for instance. Something similar should be available in Java. This way, what you store in the cookie is a 'reference' to the confidential data and the confidential data is stored on the server side (which is, supposedly, at least as secure as the entire server is).